# How to use windows authentication and register custom auth manager

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0, windows-authentication, impersonation

I am working on securing a RESTFul service.

All clients are windows intranet clients, I would like to use Windows integrated authentication. As an initial implementation, I would like to perform authorisation checks on the end user's credentials and give users access to 'read' methods on a service and give access to the write methods on the service to service accounts. I am experiencing a host of different issues in getting any of this working. I have read a large amount of articules in various places, but none so far have prevailed.
The following is the config in web.config for the application.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name ="SecureREST" behaviorConfiguration="RESTAuthorisationBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="default" contract="Service.ISecureService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="default">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTAuthorisationBehaviour">
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Security.RESTAuthorisationManager"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In IIS I have disabled anonymous authentication. I need to do this since we want all clients to be authenticated so we can then perform authorisation checks. I have also enabled Windows authentication (NTLM?).

The first issue I have is when I test this from a browser, I get the following error message:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

I don't want to enable anon authentication so it appears there is some config somewhere else that is indicating Anon authentication which is clearly at odds with the fact that I have disabled it. Where else do I need to specify that Anon authentication is not allowed?
(You will also see that I have not used any mex endpoints which according to various articles can be a cause of this problem).

The next issue I have is that I am trying to register a custom authorisation manager. The reason for this is that I want to check what groups the user is a member of and make the authorisation decision based upon that. Eg if a user is a member of group named 'ReadOnly', then they can only invoke the get method on the service. If the client is a member of group 'ReadAndWrite' then they can also invoke put methods on the service.

You should see that I have attempted to register an authorisation class (derived from ServiceauthorisationManager); this is expressed within the RESTAuthorisationBehaviour behavior. I have put some logging into this class, but none of this is displayed in the logs, so I know it is not registered properly.

The final issue is with Impersonation. To test this, inside the service code, I am accessing the WindowIdentity and displaying it in the logs. What I'm finding is that the the user name does not represent the end user which is what I need so I can perform the authorisation checks previously described. Instead what I'm seeing is the the user is an application pool identity ('**IIS APPPOOL\SecureREST**'). This is of no use to me. I have switched on the impersonate flag (as you can see from the config), but how do I get it to work so that the real clients credentials are represented in the WindowsIdentity object? The code I'm using to get hold of the windows identity is as follows:

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string accountName = windowsIdentity.Name;
```

I have also tried calling the Impersonate method on the windowsIndentity object to no avail.

So how do I impersonate the authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the exception about anonymous authentication, try disabling http get metadata within your service behavior like so:

```
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
```